# Embedded service deployment styling missing

Tags: servicecloud, react, embedded-services, shadow-dom

We've been using the Service cloud chat (Embedded service deployment) since january withouth any issues.
However since this week we've notice styling is missing which breaks the UI of the chat (big buttons, no close or minimize buttons). The styling in this case seems to ony be the styling applied in the branding section in the Salesforce settings

The issue seems to be specific to our website which is built using React. I've installed the chat on a blank page elsewhere and it renders just fine. Both with or without Google Tag Manager.

The core issue seems to be that the chat is put in to a **#shadow-root** element on our webiste which containerizes it form the rest. The rest including the styling...

Has any one encountered this issue before? Is there a way to still apply this styling or remove the shadow-root implementation?

[image: shadow root]

Comment: Was the Winter '24 release rolled out in your org this week?

Comment: Nope, we're still on summer '23...

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue, where you able to find a workaround/fix for this?